# SelfJoin to exclude same records from table in Sql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to ignore records where startDate, endDate & code are same for different meter for each account. (one account can have 2 meters and each meter have startdate, enddate and code)

Sample Table

```
Account Meter   STARTDATE   ENDDATE     Code            
1       101     4/10/2019   4/9/2020    ***Custom***    
1       109     4/10/2019   4/9/2020    ***Custom***            
1       101     4/22/2020   12/31/9999  HOLDOVER-ETF0_APR20 
1       109     4/22/2020   12/31/9999  HOLDOVER-ETF0_APR20         
2       202     1/25/2020   4/23/2020   GE_PMD_JAN20    
2       208     2/24/2020   4/23/2020   GE_PMD_JAN20            
2       202     4/24/2020   12/31/9999  GE-V-STD-ETF0
2       208     4/24/2020   12/31/9999  GE-V-STD-ETF0
```

Expected Result

```
2       202     1/25/2020   4/23/2020   GE_PMD_JAN20    
2       208     2/24/2020   4/23/2020   GE_PMD_JAN20
```

I have tried below query but this is returning me the once which has same start date,end date and code.

```sql
select m1.account,
       m1.meter,
       m1.STARTDATE,
       m1.ENDDATE,
       m1.Code
from #MultipleMeter m1
     join #MultipleMeter m2 on m1.account = m2.account 
where m1.meter <> m2.meter 
  and m1.STARTDATE <> m2.STARTDATE 
  and m1.ENDDATE <> m2.ENDDATE
  and m1.Code <> m2.Code
group by m1.account,
          m1.meter,
          m1.STARTDATE,
          m1.ENDDATE,
          m1.code
order by account,
         STARTDATE
```

How do I rewrite query to get only records which has different start date, end date and code ?

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` when you don't have any aggregation ?

Comment: As for your question, **consumable** sample data (*not* an image) and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu, I have changed from image to Sample data

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this will do what you mean?

```
SELECT m1.account,
       m1.meter,
       m1.STARTDATE,
       m1.ENDDATE,
       m1.Code
FROM #MultipleMeter m1
        LEFT JOIN #MultipleMeter m2
            ON m1.account = m2.account 
            AND m1.StartDate = m2.StartDate
            AND m1.EndDate = m2.EndDate
            AND m1.Code = m2.Code
            AND m1.Meter < m2.Meter 
WHERE
    m2.Account IS NULL 
ORDER BY 
    m1.Account,
    m1.StartDate
```

My only question in that - the wording implies you could possibly want the m1 and m2 result *both* removed where there's a duplicate? I'm not sure why this would be useful but it's not my problem to solve. If that genuinely is what you want,

```
SELECT m1.account,
       m1.meter,
       m1.STARTDATE,
       m1.ENDDATE,
       m1.Code
FROM Meters m1
        FULL JOIN Meters m2
            ON m1.account = m2.account 
            AND m1.StartDate = m2.StartDate
            AND m1.EndDate = m2.EndDate
            AND m1.Code = m2.Code
            AND NOT m1.Meter = m2.Meter 
WHERE
    m2.Account IS NULL 
ORDER BY 
    m1.Account,
    m1.StartDate
```

I think does it?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/289704/4